# How can a question with multiple answers have just 1 view?

Tags: discussion, views, time

It was observed on [English Language Learners beta](https://ell.stackexchange.com/); but I think is applicable for other SE websites too.

While answering(and after answering) [this question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/4155/833) on [ELL SE](https://ell.stackexchange.com/); I noticed that the number of views on the question were **1**. I refreshed(<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd>) the page, and it still was 1. I then moved back to the home page; and once more it was just *1 view*.

[image: Img 2]

How can a question with 2 replies be stuck at just one view?

**P.S.**: You can also notice that the view count hasn't changed from 1 even after 10 minutes from the first reply:

[image: Img 3]

Comment: Caching, it's always caching...

Comment: @Yannis Even after half an hour?

Comment: Also, [THIS](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/172315/212576) question has already struck a count of 5 views in 3 minutes.

Comment: Yes, but this question is on MSO, not on a beta site. Betas don't get much traffic, so longer TTLs make sense. Only a SE dev can answer this authoritatively, but... it's caching ;)

Comment: @BackinaFlash - Yep. I have observed the same in Sports.SE.

Comment: This is server cache, F5 or clearing browser cache won't help. Anyway my guess is that the cache is updated in "bulks", i.e. not after every single view but rather after 5, 10, 15 etc. This explains the behavior.

Comment: hmm. It changed to `4` views after 40 minutes.

Comment: @Yannis Do you really think caching a question with only 1 view makes sense?

Comment: @pvorb the views are cached, not the question. Instead of going to the live table each time the code is going to a cache and that cache updates every X minutes, maybe depending on other factors as well.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd This might be the case, but isn't caching usually only useful when done for more frequently used objects? (But I'm not a SE dev, so I can't tell)

Comment: @pvorb: The views of 20ish questions are fetched _every time someone opens the main page_

Comment: @pvorb the point behind caching is avoiding expansive trips to database; on Stack Exchange virtually everything is cached otherwise their database would work slower than a tied up turtle. :)

Comment: @Manishearth You are right. I didn't realize that.

Comment: While not even google seems to know what the speed of a tied up turtle is I must assume it is not very fast. This issue seems to be an edge case of speed over functionality.

Comment: @TravisJ An African or European tied-up turtle?